# Same code works differently if compare Codewars compilation and MVS2019

Tags: c#

**Task from codewars**

> Write an algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses in dot-decimal format. IPs should be considered valid if they consist of
>   four octets, with values between 0 and 255, inclusive.
>
> Input to the function is guaranteed to be a single string.
>
> Examples Valid inputs:
>
> 1.2.3.4
>   123.45.67.89 Invalid inputs:
>
> 1.2.3
>   1.2.3.4.5
>   123.456.78.90
>   123.045.067.089 Note that leading zeros (e.g. 01.02.03.04) are considered invalid.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


//Write an algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses in dot-decimal format.
//IPs should be considered valid if they consist of four octets, with values between 0 and 255, inclusive.

//Input to the function is guaranteed to be a single string.

//Examples
//Valid inputs:

//1.2.3.4
//123.45.67.89
//Invalid inputs:

//1.2.3
//1.2.3.4.5
//123.456.78.90
//123.045.067.089
//Note that leading zeros (e.g. 01.02.03.04) are considered invalid.





namespace IPValidation
{
    class Kata
    {
        static int ipnumber = 0;

        static bool numberChecker(List<char> number)
        {
            string checkNum = null;
            foreach (char symb in number)
            {
                checkNum += symb.ToString();
            }
            try
            {
                byte result = Convert.ToByte(checkNum);
                if (result.ToString() == (checkNum).ToString())
                {
                    ipnumber++;
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool is_valid_IP(string ipAddres)
        {                             
            bool getOut = false;
            ipAddres = ipAddres + '.';
            char[] ipArray = ipAddres.ToCharArray();
            List<char> check = new List<char>();          
            foreach (char symbol in ipArray)
            {
                if (check.Contains('.'))
                    break;
                if (symbol == '.')
                {                    
                    getOut = numberChecker(check);
                    if (!getOut)
                        break;
                    check.Clear();
                }
                else
                check.Add(symbol);                              
            }
            if (getOut == true && ipnumber == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }        
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            bool num = Kata.is_valid_IP("43.99.196.187");
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

> result will be **True**

But codewars test giving me something like that:
[ScreenshotFromCodewars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmi2o.png)

Have no idea why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class as a `static` state: `static int ipnumber = 0;`

So if you only test *one* case, it might work, but if somebody else ran multiple tests, the results may vary.

The easiest way to find out what's wrong would be to actually run the same testcases as seen in the screenshot and debug it. The solution will most likely be to get rid of that static state in your method.

Comment: Closed program with: ipnumber = 0 and all was good ! Thank you very much! if (getOut == true && ipnumber == 4)
            {
                ipnumber = 0;
                return true;
            }
            else {
            ipnumber=0;
            return false; }